# Symfony4 does not load the .env

Tags: nginx, symfony4

Differnt to my local dev environmet my prod (Debian, Nginx, PHP 7.1.22) environment is not loading the .env config file.

I always get the Symfony error: `Environment variable not found`.

Answer (score 8):

Just want to mention the solution to the problem which I couldn't find in the web.

Finally I checked the index.php file were the .env is initially loaded and found the following lines:

```
if (!isset($_SERVER['APP_ENV'])) {
  if (!class_exists(Dotenv::class)) {
    throw new \RuntimeException('APP_ENV environment variable is not defined. You need to define environment variables for configuration or add "symfony/dotenv" as a Composer dependency to load variables from a .env file.');
  }
  (new Dotenv())->load(__DIR__.'/../.env');
}
```

Means that if the env var `APP_ENV` is already set in the web server config the .env will not be loaded.

So I checked also my nginx config for my website and removed the fpm env config line `fastcgi_param APP_ENV "prod";`

Now it works.

Hope this helps you, too ;)

Comment: Thanks a lot for this, I had exactly the same problem. Its also such a non-obvious reason as well. Because APP_ENV specifically is already set on the server. Really? How would you figure that out?